# Spring JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer Polling frequency

Tags: jms, spring-jms, polling, message-listener

I am using the DefaultMessageListenerContainer for consuming messages from ActiveMQ queue as below. With this implementation is there any polling mechanism, does the listener poll the queue to see if there is a new message every 1 second or so , or does the onMessage method get invoked whenever there is a new message in the queue? If it uses polling how can we increase or decrease the polling frequency (time) .

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
container.setMessageListener(new MessageJmsListener ());

public class MessageJmsListener implements MessageListener {
    
  @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                //process the message and create record in Data Base                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container polls the JMS client, but the broker pushes messages to the client.

So, no, the container does not poll the queue directly.

If there are no messages in the queue, the container will timeout after `receiveTimeout` and immediately re-poll and will get the next message as soon as the broker sends it.

The prefetch determines how many messages are sent to the consumer by the broker; so that might impact performance (but it's 1000 by default, I think, with recent ActiveMQ versions).

Setting the prefetch to 1 will give you the slowest delivery rate.

If you want to slow things down, you can add a `Thread.sleep()` in your listener.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please point me to any documentation for this. I could not find much details.

Comment: am new here. Please clarify. Is recievTimeOut not applicable when using Asynchronous reception with MessageListener as above.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html  21.4.1 Synchronous Reception
.. it is possible to consume messages synchronously. During a synchronous receive, calling thread blocks until  message becomes available. This can be a dangerous operation since the calling thread can potentially be blocked indefinitely. The property receiveTimeout specifies how long  receiver should wait before giving up waiting for  message.

Comment: Please don't use 3.0.x documentation; the current spring release is 5.3.x https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#learn 3.0.x has not been supported for many years. For async, the container's `receiveTimeout` has little or no effect on delivery rates, when the receive times out, the container immediately tries another receive. Increasing the `receiveTimeout` might be useful to reduce the amount of logging when DEBUG logging is enabled. Increasing it too much will also make the container less responsive to `stop()` calls, since the stop will not take effect until the receive times out.

Comment: container is inside the JVM (say for java). Is the JMS client the listener or the SQS queue on AWS side? what about the broker?